# GetRows method created by dataset returns null

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I'm using SQLite and a Dataset. In my database I have tables that reference each other. Let's call them Table1, Table2,... Here's a representation of a EER diagram I'll use as an exaple:

[image]

I get the data from the dataset in the form of a Table1Row and that object has very usefull generated method `Table2Row[] table1Row.GetTable2Rows()` and a generated `Table3Row` parameter if you can only have one reference to Table3. But if I call this method the result I get is an empty collection and the parameter is null. All other attributes are correct and I am quite certain that the tables are filled correctly.

My selection query is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key = @key;
```

But even if I use the predefined getData the problem persists. After that I use the TableAdapter to get the correct Row:

```
Table1DataTable table1DataTable = table1TableAdapter.GetDataByKey();
return table1DataTable.FindByKey(key);
```

It is very difficult to find the solution to this problem because the names of the generated methods always differ.

Thank you for your help

Edit:
Here is the generated method:

```
    public virtual DataSet.Table1DataTable GetDataByKey(long key) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((long)(key));
        DataSet.Table1DataTable dataTable = new DataSet.Table1DataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: `GetRows method created by dataset returns null` I think you may have forgotten to include that code in your post.

Comment: No, I just didn't find that part very useful since the standard GetData method doesn't work either I don't think this is the problem. I think it's more that either the entire approach is wrong or there is an extra step that I'm missing after getting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution. You need to fill the other tables using the same dataset and not using the getData methods. Then it works like this:

```
        DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter table1TableAdapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter ();
        table1TableAdapter.FillByKey(dataset.Table1,key);

        DataSetTableAdapters.Table2TableAdapter table2TableAdapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.Table2TableAdapter();
        table2TableAdapter.Fill(dataset.Table2);

        DataSetTableAdapters.Table3TableAdapter table3TableAdapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.Table3TableAdapter();
        table3TableAdapter.Fill(dataset.Table3);

        return dataset.Table1.FindBykey(key);
```

Now all I have to do is optimize it so that I won't get all the data I don't need from table 2 and 3.